# Laravel link with params while updating some existing params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Say I have a url: www.site.com/search?category=1&sub_category_id=1

On the page which display results I have links to refine such as:

```
<a href="{!! $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !!}&sub_category_id=1">Category 1</a>
<a href="{!! $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !!}&sub_category_id=2">Category 2</a>
<a href="{!! $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !!}&sub_category_id=3">Category 3</a>
<a href="{!! $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !!}&sub_category_id=4">Category 4</a>
```

Issue is it just keeps appending another &sub_category_id=# each time... When I actually want it to update. Googling for ever I find this which is almost what I need:

```
{!! link_to_action('SearchController@search', 'Sub Cat 1', Input::all()) !!}
```

Issue here is how to "update" the existing sub_category_id... Tried Input::merge but that doesn't send all the output in addition to my merge.

My ideal approach is to somehow to this (as I want to link to URL not controller):

`{!! HTML::link('/search', 'Sub Category 1", Input::all()->merge(['sub_category_id' => 1')) !!}`

Within Laravel pagination we can do `->appends(Input::except('page'))` Was hoping perhaps it would be possible to add that into a link scenario somehow?

but Laravel doesn't work like that doesn't work, any ideas? I'd link to do all this in my link (if possible) rather than create a function to get all the params update and then put back into a url... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you have the `Request` facade (use `Input` in Laravel 4). So you can achieve this thing in many ways reading the [documentation](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html). The easiest one line solution will be to get all of the input paremeters except `sub_category_id` and then just append yours:

```
 {!! link_to_action('SearchController@search', 'Sub Cat 1', 'Test', array_merge(Request::except(['sub_category_id']), ['sub_category_id' => 1]))) !!}
```

Comment: Question, won't then my link {!! link_to_action('SearchController@search', 'Sub Cat 2', 'Cat 2', Request::all())) !!} go to sub_category_id 1 as well when it should go to 2? This is the issue I have where I just want to resend the same params but updated via the links.

Comment: @sprintcar78a Yes, that is right, you should do the merge everythime you want to change `sub_category_id`. It is the same like you have to pass different array each time. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay awesome, (sorry didn't think initially to add before each link) - it's working. Is it possible to do this by another function using the actual URL and append i.e. '/search', Request::all() rather than having to use the controller? Doesn't really matter but feel it reads easier for me.

Comment: Yes, you can use `{!! link_to_action('SearchController@search', 'Sub Cat 1', 'Test', array_merge(Request::except('sub_category_id'), ['sub_category_id' => 1]))) !!}` if you want one line solution. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Great - Thank you! Okay just found out it pays to also add 'page' to the Request::except() if using pagination so it will restart at page one on a category change. i.e. if on page 5 and next category only has 2 pages it brings up a blank :)